# Remove fake path in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am new to the extjs.Please help me to remove fakepath issue in filefield.I do not want to get the exact path .Removing "fakepath" string is ok for me. Code runs perfectly but path displays as C:\fakepath....
I created a seperate window inorder to upload a file. In my case Application should have a seperate window as a result of selecting a option from the menu. 
Here is crateWindow function of my code :

```
    createWindow: function() {
    var desktop = teamApp.getDesktop();
    var win = desktop.getWindow(this.windowId + '_win');
    if(!win) {
        win = desktop.createWindow({
            id: this.windowId + '_win',
            title: 'Upload a Audio',
            iconCls: 'icon-upload-picture',
            height:150,
            width: 500,                
            layout: 'fit',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items:
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                frame:true,
                bodyPadding: '10',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    id: 'form-file',
                    labelWidth: 100,
                    //emptyText: 'Select an audio file',
                    fieldLabel: 'Audio File',
                    name: 'file-path',
                    fieldWidth: 250,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    buttonText: 'Browse'
                }],

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: function(){
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                        if(form.isValid()){
                            form.submit({
                                //url: 'file-upload.php',
                                waitMsg: 'Uploading your Audio file...',
                                success: function(fp, o) {
                                    msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
    }
    win.show();
    return win;
}
```

Comment: Where is that `fakepath` in your code ?

Comment: fakepath is browser dependent. Some browsers display the fullpath, some just display the name of the file, and some display something like C:\fakepath\{filename}. As per, [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp)  
"The value property returns the path or the name of the file selected with the <input type="file"> element. This property returns the name of the selected file with a fake path in IE, Google Chrome, and Opera, and the name of the selected file in Firefox and Safari. Note: This property is read-only, because of security reasons."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you cannot, as per documentation at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

> Because there is no secure cross-browser way to programmatically set the value of a file input, the standard Field setValue method is not implemented. The getValue method will return a value that is browser-dependent; some have just the file name, some have a full path, some use a fake path.

**Update**

What you can do is set fieldWidth to zero and add another textfield before the filefield. You can set the value of this textfield as the name of file selected by user by listening to change of file field and parsing the value from last index of \ till last.